# huge text file (6Gb) search and replace

Tags: python, perl, shell, sed, awk

I have a huge file (6Gb) with 74.000 articles in this format:

```
<text id="1">
bla bla bla bla.........
</text>
<text id="2">
bla bla bla bla.........
</text>
<text id="3">
bla bla bla bla.........
</text>
<text id="............ and so on untill 74.000
```

then I have another file having the title corresponding to each of the id's, like this:

```
1       title1
2       title2
3       title3
...
74000   title74000
```

I have to put the corresponding title to each of the id's in the first file so I transformed the second file into this script:

```
sed -i "s/<text id="1">/<text id="1" title="title1">/" file1
sed -i "s/<text id="2">/<text id="2" title="title2">/" file1
sed -i "s/<text id="3">/<text id="3" title="title3">/" file1
...
sed -i "s/<text id="74000">/<text id="74000" title="title74000">/" file1
```

Notice I didn't put the g at the end of sed command because it is not global serch, that means at the first match it changes the string and goes to the next search. The script works, but due to the huge size of the file it takes 12 minutes per change, that gives me about two years to complete all the changes while I need them ASAP, so my question is if somebody knows how can I perform this changes in a faster way, maybe with some other utility, python, perls or any other...

Comment: I guess you'd be better off iterating the file line by line. awk seems to be a good choice for that.

Comment: can you give me an example please....

Comment: The numbers in the first column in the second file seems redundant.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, fixed

Comment: @AndrésChandía: sorry, I don't know awk, but I added the tag, hope some _awkward_ person will be able to help you.

Comment: In the first file, there seems to be two tags with `id=2`..

Comment: thanks, I couldn't put that tag because I had 5 already

Comment: Are the numbers in the first column of the second file necessary? (Seems like they are sequentially ordered..)

Comment: if you mean id="X" yes numbers are totally necessary, they identify each article together with the title

Comment: Running `sed` just once with multiple replacements might also be faster.

Comment: @nrathaus can you suggest something

Comment: choroba can you exemplify

Comment: Are the lines in the second file in the *same order* as the `<text>` tags in the first? And is there exactly one title for each tag?

Comment: yes, it is exactly that situation

Comment: Also, do the data file really have six spaces at the start of each line?

Comment: no, sorry, no spaces at all

Comment: if possible split file and then run sed/awk command on all splitted files in a dir, that might work faster as search time will be less because of low file volume

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use something like this.

It reads a line from the titles file every time it comes across a `<text>` tag in the XML file, and inserts the `title` attribute into the tag.

It also checks that the IDs in the two files match, and prints a log output every 500 `<text>` elements so that you can see its progress.

Output is sent to a separate file. You shouldn't overwrite the input file as if something goes wrong you have lost your original data.

This should be only fractionally slower than just copying the XML file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Handle;

STDOUT->autoflush;

open my $in_xml,    '<', 'input.xml'  or die "Failed to open XML file: $!";
open my $in_titles, '<', 'titles.txt' or die "Failed to open titles file: $!";
open my $out_xml,   '>', 'output.xml' or die "Failed to open output file: $!";

while (my $xml_line = <$in_xml>) {

  if ( $xml_line =~ /<text/ ) {

    my ($id1) = $xml_line =~ /id="(\d+)"/;
    unless (defined $id1) {
      chomp;
      die sprintf qq{Error in input XML file at line %d: %s\n-}, $in_xml->input_line_number, $_;
    }
    printf "Processing ID %d\n", $id1 unless $id1 % 500;

    my $title_line = <$in_titles>;
    my ($id2, $title) = $title_line =~ /^(\d+)\s+(.+)/;
    unless (defined $id2) {
      chomp $title_line;
      die sprintf qq{Error in input titles file at line %d: %s\n-}, $in_titles->input_line_number, $title_line;
    }

    unless ($id1 == $id2) {
      die sprintf "ID mismatch %d <=> %d\nXML file line %d\ntitles file line %d\n-",
          $id1, $id2, $in_xml->input_line_number, $in_titles->input_line_number
    }

    $xml_line =~ s/>/ title="$title">/;
  }

  print $out_xml $xml_line;
}

close $out_xml or die "Failed to close output file: $!";
```

**output**

```
<text id="1" title="title1">
bla bla bla bla.........
</text>
<text id="2" title="title2">
bla bla bla bla.........
</text>
<text id="3" title="title3">
bla bla bla bla.........
</text>
```

Comment: That is what i would do as well. But i would direct the output to a file internally and print the current id to STDOUT every ten or one hundred ids. This will still run for quite a while.

Comment: @DeVadder: Yes I agree and I've improved it.

Comment: Thanks to you both guys, I have copied and edited the file but on running it it tells me: Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console<br>
./scrip2.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `)'<br>
./scrip2.sh: line 8: `while (<$in_xml>) {'

Comment: @AndrésChandía: I can't tell the problem without seeing your code. That is an Ubuntu message, not a Perl one. It looks like your problem is in `scrip2.sh`. I suggest you run the Perl program directly from the command line to check that it works on its own.

Comment: script2.sh is an exact copy of your code, except for the file names, sorry for my ignorance, but how can I ran all that code that I copied to the file script2.sh straight from the command line?

Comment: sorry, my fault, at first line of the script I had: #!usr/bin/perl, there was a slash missing, changed to #!/usr/bin/perl and started to run

Comment: The script is runnig perfectly, when it first found an error on the origin file it told me: Use of uninitialized value $id1 in modul (%) at ./scrip2.sh line 15, <$in_xml> line 22168151.
Processing ID 0
Use of uninitialized value $id1 in numeric eq (==) at ./scrip2.sh line 19, <$in_titles> line 40630. As you ca see, line at the first part is not = to line in the second part. first part actual origin file line, line in second part is actualy the id, next error dind't told me the first part line, only the problematic id, but the error is before that, some code produces it, I need the line to fix

Comment: so how can I get that info?

Comment: @AndrésChandía: I see. You confused me by naming your Perl file `scrip2.sh`. Anything ending in `.sh` is normally a shell script. Perl files generally end with `.pl`. I thought you had written a shell script to execute the Perl program.

Comment: @AndrésChandía: OK I've added more diagnostics to the code. It checks that both the XML and the titles file records are formatted correctly as well as that the ID numbers match, and dumps the input file line numbers in all cases if there is an error. Note that the line numbers from the two files *should* be different: there are lines in the XML between those that contain `<text>` tags that add to the line count. And `40630` is equal to *both* the line number and the ID because the IDs are numbered sequenatially, one per line.

Comment: it tells me "Can't locate object method "autoflush" via package "IO::Handle" at ./xmlscript.pl line 5." and my first line is "#!/usr/bin/perl"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45598/discussion-between-borodin-and-andres-chandia)

Answer (score 4):

In Gnu Awk version 4, you could try:

```
gawk4 -f a.awk file2 RS="^$" file1
```

where `a.awk` is:

```
NR==FNR {
   b["<text id=\""$1"\">"]=$2
   next
}

{
    n=split($0,a,/<text id=[^>]*>/,s)
    printf "%s%s",s[0],a[1]
    for (i=1; i<n; i++) {
        ind=index(s[i],">")
        printf "%s%s", substr(s[i],1,ind-1) " title=\""b[s[i]]"\">", a[i+1]
    }
    printf "%s",s[n]
}
```

Output:

```
<text id="1" title="title1">
  bla bla bla bla.........
</text>
<text id="2" title="title2">
  bla bla bla bla.........
</text>
<text id="3" title="title3">
  bla bla bla bla.........
</text>
```

**Update**

Just for fun, I tested some of the solutions here on 3.9Mb xml file (80000 titles) and a 1.3Mb info file (also 80000 titles)

- @HåkonHægland : 0.629s
- @tangent      : 0.645s
- @Borodin      : 0.718s
- @glennjackman : 1.098s

(Scripts for generating the input files can be found here: http://pastebin.com/PpTPt0gk )

**Update 2**

To get more reliable timing results I took an average over 20 runs:

- @EdMorton     : 0.485s (Gnu Awk version 4.1)
- @EdMorton     : 0.528s (Gnu Awk version 3.1.8)
- @HåkonHægland : 0.589s
- @Borodin      : 0.599s
- @tangent      : 0.626s
- @glennjackman : 1.074s

Comment: Why did you not include the Ops version, that is the one i would be most interested in. ^^ And now that i think about, i am kind of curious as to how tangent can beat Borodin. They do the same think in different orders, imho.

Comment: @DeVadder The original posters script is extremely slow. Only doing the top 10 (of the 80000) inplace `sed` edits takes 5.736s, doing 20 edits takes 11.480s, so doing all 80000 lines would take over 12 hours :)

Comment: @HåkonHægland: If you have run the programs just *once* each, then those numbers are indistinguishable. I agree with DeVadder: I don't see how anything can be faster than just reading through both files once.

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Thanks. Nice effort and nice answer.

Comment: sorry guys it is giving me this: gawk: a.awk:7: fatal: 4 is invalid as number of arguments for split

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
    id = $1
    sub(/^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,"")
    map["<text id=\"" id "\">"] = "<text id=\"" id "\" title=\"" $0 "\">"
    next
}
$0 in map { $0 = map[$0] }
1
' file2 file1
```

If file2 is tab-separated it gets simpler and, I expect, faster:

```
awk -F'\t' '
NR==FNR {
    map["<text id=\"" $1 "\">"] = "<text id=\"" $1 "\" title=\"" $2 "\">"
    next
}
$0 in map { $0 = map[$0] }
1
' file2 file1
```

Comment: Thanks. It'd be faster still if "file2" is tab-separated as then I could get rid of the sub() and just use $2 to populate map[] (see my updated script I just added) but I don't know if that's the situation or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach with GNU awk

```
gawk '
    NR == FNR { title[NR] = $0; next }
    match($0, /<text id="([[:digit:]]+)">/, m) {
        sub(/>/, " title=\"" title[m[1]] "\">")
    }
    {print}
' titles articles
```

awk keeps 2 counters: `FNR` is the record number within the current file being processed; `NR` is the record number of all records processed so far. The condition `NR == FNR` is true for all records in the first file.

You need GNU awk for the extension tot he match() function, the 3rd parameter which is an array to store the matched portions of the regex.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's|^([0-9]+)\s*(.*)|/(<text id="\1")(>)/s//\\1 title="\2"\\2/|;t;d' file2 |
sed -rf - file1
```

Runs a sed script against the file holding the titles to produce a sed script to run against the source file.

Beware of metacharacters in the titles!

Comment: I tried your code just to compare speed with the other solutions here. But it seems to be extremely slow. It seems that it is the last part (`sed -rf - file1`) that is slow.. The first part runs quickly.. Any idea why? Maybe I did something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another Perl version. It first reads all the titles into a hash, then copies each line from your original file to a new file, substituting when necessary.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open (my $title_file, '<', 'titles.txt') or die "Could not open titles.txt, $!";
my %titles;
while (<$title_file>) {
    chomp;
    my ($id,$title) = split(m/\s+/,$_,2);
    $titles{$id} = $title;
}
close $title_file;

open (my $in_file, '<', 'in.txt') or die "Could not open in.txt, $!";
open (my $out_file, '>', 'out.txt') or die "Could not open out.txt, $!";
while (<$in_file>) {
    if (m/<text id=/) {
        s/<text id="(\d+)">/<text id="$1" title="$titles{$1}">/;
    }
    print $out_file $_;
}
close $in_file;
close $out_file;
```

Comment: Data like that should be in an *array*, not a hash.

Comment: If the titles were not ordered, a hash would be better.

Comment: @Borodin do you mean the titles? If so I think a hash is better. And what if either file is not in strict order - an array would fail there.

Comment: @tangent: Yes I mean the titles. They are numerically-indexed from 1 to 74,000 with no gaps. That is where an array is best. You can insert data into an array in any order you like.

Comment: @DeVadder: Even if the titles were out of order an array is the better solution.

Comment: @Borodin: Hmm, you are of course right. But if the ids were something else than integers! Okay, i admit, an array is better despite the small additional work to set it up for unordered titles and data.

Comment: @DeVadder: Set it up? You don't need to preallocate the array, if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: I know. I meant how it is slightly more complicated to write the app using an array. But of course it is not really. I was joking about how your clearly correct statement might fail in some wierd cornercases so mine would not have been completely stupid. And then i proceeded to look as stupid as possible... Yay me.

Answer (score 1):

make a first file for your sed instruction from file having peer ID - Title

```
sed 's|\([0-9]\{1,\}\)[[:blank:]]*\([^[:blank:]].*\)|/<text id="\1"/ {s/>/ title="\2">/\
   b\
   }|' ID_Title_File > /tmp/ID_Chg.sed
```

2 accelerator (compare to your version)

1. make all the action in the same sed (no restart of sed per substitution that is time consuming, especially on such number of line)
2. after a succesull find, replace the end than skip rest of the action for the
   same line (so no more test for this occurance

treat your huge file from this action list

```
sed -unbuffer -f /tmp/ID_Chg.sed file1 > Output
```

For GNU sed you maybe need a -posix option (test made on KSH/AIX)

Just for test purpose:

```
Increment=$((80000 / 128));echo "" > /tmp/ID_Chg.sed;Iter=0;while [ $Iter -lt 80000 ]; do echo "/id=\"$Iter\""/ b r$Iter >> /tmp/ID_Chg.sed; let Iter+=Increment; done
sed 's|\([0-9]\{1,\}\)[[:blank:]]*\([^[:blank:]].*\)|:r\1\
```

/^/ title="\2">/\
   b\
   }|' ID_Title.lst >> /tmp/ID_Chg.sed

where 80000 is the number of ID and 128 number of sub section ("accelerator") wanted

Comment: I tried your first `sed` command, but I get error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 92: unterminated `s' command`

Comment: sorry, bad copy, changed in answer

Comment: What is the purpose of the double quote after the star in you first sed command ( `([^[:blank:]].*"\)`? Are you assuming that the titles are within double quotes? (If you look at the question, they are not within double qoutes.. )

Comment: right, it was in my different test with title having white space and double quote, i remove it

Comment: Shouldn't it be `--unbuffered` for your second `sed` command? (Not `-unbuffer`)

Comment: accelerator is still possible by jumping to portion of action to test depending of id 'range' . Ex: a range of 1000 or 100 possible id (to avoid 1 label/jump per ID)

Comment: Sorry, I am not very familiar with `sed`.. So I am not sure what you mean by that. I just get error messages when I use `-unbuffer`.. So therefore I wondered if you really meant `--unbuffered`?

Comment: certainly (i have no GNU sed here), this is the equivalent to -u on AIX to work without buffering the file before working on (stream  version)

Comment: Ok:) Now it works.. Seems to be an improvement over the method of the original poster (which used over 12 hours).. I think this method will use approx. 1 hour.. To process the first 100 titles (of the 80000) it uses around 6 seconds..